# Advertised Listeners and Kafka Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I am struggling to setup a Kafka Cluster.

I have 3 x Zookeepers which work well.

3 x 3 x Kafkas which seem to connect to the Zookeepers and look healthy in the logs.

However, I cannot connect to Kafka from any clients or command line tools, and don't get anything in the logs.

Anything I might be missing?

35.178.24.18 is my AWS public IP (since destroyed)

```
consumer.properties:
broker.id=0
port=9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://35.178.24.18:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
zookeeper.connect=35.178.24.18:2181,18.130.74.2:2181,35.178.153.165:2181
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove `port=9092`. Add `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` and ensure the VPC is open

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's a debugging issue, if you are using pre-packaged command line tools like `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh`, then you can increase the log level that's present in `config/tools-log4j.properties` (the paths assume you are in middle of unpacked kafka directory).

Other than that, have you verified you can actually connect to the server via something like telnet/netcat.